# adding waypoints in the react-google-maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

[editable samplecode](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#!/DirectionsRenderer/1) how to use waypoints in the following code  does the waypoints helps to plot the way which I updated in the database wheather the ponits will be based on the points I have updated

```
const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                 const  DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true},{strokeColor:"#4a4a4a"});

      DirectionsService.route({

        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.orgin.latitude ,this.state.orgin.longitude),
         destination: new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.destination.latitude ,this.state.destination.longitude),
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,

      }, 
       (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result,
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      });

            }).catch(function (err) {

            });

    }

  })

)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={50}>
     <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions}   />

  < Marker

  position={{  lat:props.delivery!=undefined?props.delivery.latitude:null, lng:  props.delivery!=undefined?props.delivery.longitude:null }} />

  </GoogleMap>

);
    return (
      <MapWithADirectionsRenderer />
    )
  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the above code will give the route between origin and destination based on google routes I need to make the route based on my waypoints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add waypoints by adding waypoints[] array of DirectionsWaypoint in your Directions Request.

You can check this documentation to learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests

Here's a sample waypoints array:

```
waypoints: [
    {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(14.546748, 121.05455)
    },
    {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(14.552444,121.044488)
    }
]
```

Here's a sample Direction Request with waypoints:

```
DirectionsService.route({
   origin: new google.maps.LatLng(14.533593, 121.053128),
   destination: new google.maps.LatLng(14.550895, 121.025079),
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   waypoints: [
        {
           location: new google.maps.LatLng(14.546748, 121.05455)
        },
        {
           location: new google.maps.LatLng(14.552444,121.044488)
        }
   ]
}, (result, status) => {
   if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      this.setState({
         directions: result,
      });
   } else {
     console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
   }
});
```

Comment: ya that works how to enable default zoom button in react-native-maps ?

Comment: Glad I could help! For you new question, I recommend for you to create a new post, so that others can help you too.

Comment: check with this link    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676655/to-enable-zoom-button-in-react-native-maps

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to implement wayPoints in React

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { withScriptjs } from "react-google-maps";




import  Map from './components/Map';

function App() {

  const MapLoader = withScriptjs(Map);

  return (

<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

  </header>
  <MapLoader
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And in your Map.js file

```
/*global google*/
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    GoogleMap,
    DirectionsRenderer
} from "react-google-maps";
class Map extends Component {
    state = {
        directions: null,


};

componentDidMount() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    const origin = { lat: 6.5244, lng:  3.3792 };
    const destination = { lat: 6.4667, lng:  3.4500};

    directionsService.route(
        {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            waypoints: [
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(6.4698,  3.5852)
                },
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(6.6018,3.3515)
                }
            ]
        },
        (result, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                console.log(result)
                this.setState({
                    directions: result
                });
            } else {
                console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
            }
        }
    );
}

render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 6.5244, lng:  3.3792 }}
            defaultZoom={13}
        >
            <DirectionsRenderer
                directions={this.state.directions}
            />
        </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMapExample
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />
        </div>


       );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

I believe this is okay