# To enable zoom button in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps in my native project
I need the default zoom control button to zoom in and out
How to enable zoom button/control in react-native-maps

Comment: Going through same issue. Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: there's no default property for zoom button in react-native-maps if we need zoom button we have to create our own @HungrySoul

Comment: thats nasty, as i have seen props for it on docs (enableZoomControl). And i am also facing problem with myLocationButton. It doesnt show up sometimes. Dont know when will we get a pure google maps services into react native.

Answer (score 2):

If you rotate the screen once, with enableZoomControl=true, It will show.

My problem is that it needs that rotation of the screen(device) to show the first time.